# Can't click on buttons in HBox

Tags: java, javafx, hbox

I can't get the buttons in the `buttonContainer` `HBox` to work, as in I can't click on them at all, they are "stuck" so to speak. This happens in multiple IDEs so it can't be that. I don't understand why they are stuck without the ability to click on them, but I'm sure I'm making some kind of basic mistake.

Here's my simple code:

```
public class Game extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Button attack, run, drinkPotion, nextRoom;
    StackPane root;
    HBox buttonContainer, roomContainer;
    Scene scene;

    public void createNode() {
        root = new StackPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, 860, 640);

        attack = new Button("Attack");
        run = new Button("Run!");
        drinkPotion = new Button("Drink Potion!");
        nextRoom = new Button("Go to next room...");

        buttonContainer = new HBox(12);
        buttonContainer.getChildren().addAll(attack, run, drinkPotion);
        buttonContainer.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        roomContainer = new HBox();
        roomContainer.getChildren().addAll(nextRoom);
        roomContainer.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

        root.getChildren().addAll(buttonContainer, roomContainer);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        createNode();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is on onAction code of button?

Comment: There is no setOnAction code for this demo. The problem is that FX wouldnt let me click on a button if I had 2 groups of Buttons in the StackPane. The button was stuck in place and had no "clicked" animation to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `StackPane`, the `HBox`es are going to be resized to fill the `StackPane`. So both `HBox`es here are filling the whole area, with the alignment settings positioning the buttons inside them. Thus while the buttons don't actually overlap, the `HBox`es do.

The z-order of nodes in a `StackPane` (and other panes, in some circumstances) is determined by the order of the nodes in the `children` list. So in your code, `buttonContainer` is "behind" `roomContainer`. This means mouse clicks are targeted either to the buttons in `roomContainer`, or to `roomContainer` itself. Consequently, the buttons in `buttonContainer` never receive a mouse click.

A solution to this is to use a "real" layout container to position the two button containers appropriately. For example, you could use an `AnchorPane`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Game extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Button attack, run, drinkPotion, nextRoom;
    AnchorPane root;
    HBox buttonContainer, roomContainer;
    Scene scene;

    public void createNode() {
        root = new AnchorPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, 860, 640);

        attack = new Button("Attack");
        run = new Button("Run!");
        drinkPotion = new Button("Drink Potion!");
        nextRoom = new Button("Go to next room...");

        buttonContainer = new HBox(12);
        buttonContainer.getChildren().addAll(attack, run, drinkPotion);

        roomContainer = new HBox();
        roomContainer.getChildren().addAll(nextRoom);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(buttonContainer, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(buttonContainer, 0.0);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(roomContainer, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(roomContainer, 0.0);

        root.getChildren().addAll(roomContainer, buttonContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        createNode();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

or possibly a `BorderPane`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Game extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Button attack, run, drinkPotion, nextRoom;
    BorderPane root;
    HBox buttonContainer, roomContainer;
    Scene scene;

    public void createNode() {
        root = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(root, 860, 640);

        attack = new Button("Attack");
        run = new Button("Run!");
        drinkPotion = new Button("Drink Potion!");
        nextRoom = new Button("Go to next room...");

        buttonContainer = new HBox(12);
        buttonContainer.getChildren().addAll(attack, run, drinkPotion);
        buttonContainer.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);


        roomContainer = new HBox();
        roomContainer.getChildren().addAll(nextRoom);
        roomContainer.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);


        root.setLeft(buttonContainer);
        root.setRight(roomContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        createNode();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

You can read an overview of how all the layout panes work in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102)